# Excel (Macro) How to save column B with column A filename

Tags: excel, save, filenames, vba

My skills in Excel is not good enough so i hope you can help me here.
I have a Excel file that have numbers in column A and text in column B with 300 rows.
How can i save a txt file with each row in column B with column A filename?

Se my example here:

http://bildr.no/view/1205751

Comment: What have you tried so far in VBA to accomplish this? Show us that and we can help you where you are stuck.

Comment: http://bildr.no/view/1205802 But i dont know how to save in ex. C:\temp

Comment: My work security is pretty tight. I can't open that link. If you have VBA code in the excel file you can just edit your post and put the code in there. From there, me, or someone else can tweak it to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly there: just include the path in the `Open` statement

```
Open "C:\Temp\" & ce & ".txt" For Output As #1
```

EDIT
To avoid the `"`'s, use `Print` rather than `Write`

```
Print #1, ce.Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: + 1 Good one as always, Chris :)